# How can I make auto open one of the layout components while reloading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I'm facing a problem with nested routers! I have few nested layouts (few layouts for few services), either I have tabs with links which is a parent Layout for services layouts. Is it posible to make a default open page(service layout) by first meet the site and save an opened page after reloading.

Root of the routing. For example I need to open FirstServiceLayout by default.
Tabs were made by mui Tabs component with Link component from react-router-dom.
AppLayout component handle the Tabs component

```
<Route path='index/*' element={<AppLayout/>}>
              <Route path='first-main' element={<FirstServiceLayout/>}>
                <Route path="first-service-page-one" element={<FirstServicePageOne/>}/>
                <Route path='first-service-page-two' element={<FirstServicePageTwo/>}/>
              </Route>
              <Route path='second-main' element={<FirstServiceLayout/>}>
                  <Route path='second-service-page' element={<SecondServicePage/>}/>
              </Route>
          </Route>
```

I've tried to fetch user accesses for services and use useNavigate hook in AppLayout component to navigate the page I need.